# Access Id of Contact from lookup field

Tags: lookup

I'm working on an Opportunity trigger and trying to pull the ID of a Contact that's connected via a lookup field on the Opportunity object called "Inbound_Contact__c". However, when this gets triggered on an Opportunity that has this lookup field filled out, the following line still outputs "NULL":

```
System.debug(opp.Inbound_Contact__r.Id);
```

Am I missing something on how to access the Id of this Contact? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a relationship before you query it. For just the ID of a record, use the normal __c version of the field:

```
System.debug(opp.Inbound_Contact__c);
```

To use a __r (relationship), you have to query it first. In that case, you'd do so if you wanted extra details, like the email or phone number of the contact:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Inbound_Contact__r.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]);
```

This is generally less efficient than querying the contacts directly, if that were your intent.