# SOQL: Access Referenced object from a lookup field

Tags: soql, relationships

I had an instance where I created a lookup field on a custom object (i.e. `Sale__c`) to reference an `Opportunity`, in which case this created a relationship for the Opportunity. Meaning I could now SOQL any related custom objects using the plural API name and a "__r" suffix like so:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Customs__r) FROM Opportunity
```

But for my scenario the question was about using this relationship the other direction. When writing a query on the custom `Sale__c` object there is no relationship for me to use `Opportunities__r` like so:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r) FROM Sale__c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you can refer to the **singular API name with a "__r" suffix** without needing a nested relationship query, like so:

```
SELECT Id, Opportunity__r.CloseDate FROM Sale__c
```

As mentioned here: **[Access Id of Contact from lookup field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54518/access-id-of-contact-from-lookup-field)** this approach is not necessary when fetching the reference ID, but when you need to select other fields from that object this would be the approach.